# Car's airbag deployment system. Let's discuss the math!

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to explore the concepts and/or Calculus/Physics behind auto airbag deployment...  I am assuming the computer feeds real time velocity points and the ECU is monitoring for a sudden drop in rate of change / sudden spike in negative acceleration?

Does this seem correct? Can we try to describe what the algorithm is looking for?   ACU is fed constant speed values from the speed sensor. ACU can calculate acceleration based on time elapsed b/w 2 speed data points.

The following is just 8th grade Algebra, and I know actual ACU systems will be much more nuanced (side impact, etc), but is this the core idea involved?

VELOCITY
$$t=(milliseconds), s=(mph)$$
$$t=0, s=55$$
$$t=5, s=60$$
$$t=10, s=70$$
$$t=15, s=50$$
$$t=20, s=0$$
At time=20 the car has hit into wall and stopped suddenly!

ACCELERATION

Let's calculate some rate of change of velocity using $\frac{\delta Y}{\delta X}$:
$$\frac{60-55}{5-0}= 1 mph$$
$$\frac{70-60}{10-5}= 2 mph$$
$$\frac{50-70}{15-10}= -4 mph$$
$$\frac{0-50}{20-15}= -10 mph$$

During some interval, maybe the airbag is triggered once the acceleration exceed some negative threshold ?

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: This is an interesting read. http://auto.howstuffworks.com/car-driving-safety/safety-regulatory-devices/airbag.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'll read them tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more complicated than that.  They probably have 3 axis measurements of acceleration and angular acceleration, so can trigger on a side impact (where the forward velocity doesn't change much) and a rear impact (where the acceleration is unrealistically positive).  They also read very frequently so they can filter to avoid triggering on one bad reading.

Comment: So, am I even in the right ballpark?  Like drastic accel. delta is the basic concept behind airbag deployment?

Comment: Yes, I think you are in the ballpark.  Any time you have serious acceleration you want to deploy.  It could also be unexpected acceleration-they may take into account the throttle input to predict acceleration, but I am guessing.  Do you want to deploy the airbags if the car spins?  I don't think so.  Processing is easy, so the rules could be quite complicated trying to separate the cases you want to deploy from the others.

Comment: Gotcha.  For now, I just want to be 1 step closer to a viable hypothesis on the airbag math.  Before today, I assumed it was done by little elves and unicorns in the bumper.  Now, I think the "ACU calculates real time negative rate of change threshold" hypothesis might be more accurate, at least for the context of driving into a brick wall.